# Refresh DIV which prints a text file dynamically without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Suppose I receive a text file in a folder. I want to display the contents of the text file in a webpage, which will wait for the text file to be in that folder. Till the time the text file is not there, it will display some gif or image. As soon as the text file is in the folder, it will display the text file without reloading the whole page.

The code I wrote is as follows:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval("my_function();",5000); 
    function my_function(){
      $('#refresh').load(location.href + ' #printdiv');
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="refresh"></div>
  <div id="printdiv">
    <p><iframe id = "frame1" src="test.txt" frameborder="0" width="95%"></iframe></p>
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

However, it does not refresh until the page is reloaded. What may be the possible problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing `<script>` tag for your JQuery reference. This is causing the entire contents of the second script to be ignored.

Also, with `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()`, it's better to provide a function reference than to provide a string of executable code as the first argument.

```css
iframe { height:300px;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script>
    setInterval(my_function,5000); 
    function my_function(){
      console.log("reloading...");
      $('#refresh').load(location.href);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="refresh"></div>
  <div id="printdiv">
    <p><iframe id = "frame1" src="https://www.example.com" frameborder="0" width="95%"></iframe></p>
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. However, the automatic refresh still doesn't work. It must be the case, when "test.txt" is deleted, the content should go away, and whenever it comes back, it would print the content in "test.txt". This still does not work.

Comment: @Subhasis If you run my code, you'll see that it does work (every 5 seconds a new message is written to the console). So, if it's not working for you, there is another issue.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. However, it was reloading the whole page. However, to put a loading gif till the content arrives, can it be done only by using jquery and HTML?

Comment: No it's not reloading the whole page. It's reloading the `#refresh` element. It just so happens that that is the only visible element in my example so it appears like it's refreshing the whole page.